# Import test-users into Meteor app with use of npm script?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

We can easily create a user from meteor shell like this

```
Accounts.createUser({username: 'john', password: '12345'})
```

Similarly, I just want to add multiple users via npm script. Any ideas?

In other words, I want to use fixtures functionality via npm command and not on the initial run.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have problems with executing an npm script?

Comment: I am unable to figure out how to call UsersFixtures.js via npm script? Will it go like "node UsersFixtures.js"?

Comment: What is the use case? Dev? Test? Prod? Why npm script in particular?

Comment: @ghybs Dev. Purpose is to add data on the go, while meteor is running. Also having a choice to add the test data or not. Any other options to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For normal collections (i.e. different than `Meteor.users`), you can directly tap into your MongoDB collection. Open a Meteor Mongo shell while your project is running in development mode, then directly type Mongo shell commands.

For `Meteor.users` collection, you want to leverage the `accounts-base` and `accounts-password` packages automatic management, so instead of directly fiddling the MongoDB, you want to insert documents / users through your Meteor app.

Unfortunately, your app source files (like your `UsersFixtures.js` file) are absolutely not suitable for CLI usage.

The usual solution is to embed a dedicated method within your app server:

```js
// On your server.
// Make sure this Method is not available on production.
// When started with `meteor run`, NODE_ENV will be `development` unless set otherwise previously in your environment variables.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  Meteor.methods({
    addTestUser(username, password) {
      Accounts.createUser({
        username,
        password // If you do not want to transmit the clear password even in dev environment, you can call the method with 2nd arg: {algorithm: "sha-256", digest: sha256function(password)}
      })
    }
  });
}
```

Then start your Meteor project in development mode (`meteor run`), access your app in your browser, open your browser console, and directly call the method from there:

```
Meteor.call('addTestUser', myUsername, myPassword)
```

You could also use [`Accounts.createUser`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser) directly in your browser console, but it will automatically log you in as the new user.